Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic convex quadrilateral such that $\angle DCA = 2\angle BAC$ and $\angle BCA = 2\angle DAC$. Prove that $BC + CD = AC$.

Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic convex quadrilateral such that $\angle DCA = 2\angle BAC$ and $\angle BCA = 2\angle DAC$. Prove that $BC + CD = AC$.

I've already proved that $\angle DAB = 60^\circ$. I find that if the triangle $ADB$ is equilateral then we can apply Ptolemy's but I am kinda stuck here.
My current attempts 
We're given $\angle DCA = 2\angle BAC$ and $\angle BCA = 2\angle DAC$. Since $ABCD$ is a cyclic convex quadrilateral, $\angle DAB + \angle DCB = 180^\circ$, which is $\angle DCA + \angle BAC + \angle BCA + \angle DAC = 180^\circ$ Substiting this gives us $3\angle DAC + 3\angle CAB = 180^\circ$, which is $3\angle DAB = 180^\circ$ . Thus $\angle DAB = 60^\circ$

Please edit the question and include how you got that $\angle DAB=60^\circ$ and other attempts, otherwise the question will only attract downvotes.

You can get this result using trigonometry (i.e.Sine Rule and trig identities), but I expect you are looking for a purely geometrical proof - is that right?

Yes I tried to find a purely geometrical proof. If Ptlomey's and trig bashing works I can give it a try.
